# Declare javascript function with extra properties in a single statement?

Tags: javascript, closures

I know I can define properties on functions, which can then be accessed from within the function. Right now, the only syntax I can work out involves two statements. Is there a more concise way to express the following:

```
function myFunc() {
    // do some work
}
myFunc.myProp = 0;
```

I'm not looking for a solution that is fewer *characters* -- this isn't code golf. I'm asking something more along the lines of "are there different patterns of function declaration that have this other desirable merit?" This is almost about ways to use closures (because I suspect the answer lies there).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want a function with a property, or a plain object? I'd use an object literal: `var obj = {myprop: 0}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Especially* if you want to access properties of the function from inside the function itself, you're better off doing this:

```
var theFunction = function() {
  function theRealFunction() {
    // the code
    if (theRealFunction.something == "not whatever")
      // do something
    // more code
  }

  theRealFunction.something = "whatever";
  return theRealFunction;
}();
```

What that does is wrap your function declaration up in an anonymous function. The problem with accessing function properties via the function name is that it must do that by finding the function's name in the surrounding scope. That's kind-of icky, but at least this way it involves a scope that's essentially private. It'll work whether or not the resulting function (returned as the return value of the anonymous function) is assigned to a different variable, passed to a function as a handler function, etc.

Comment: Yes, I know about `arguments.callee`, but it's evil and not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: I don't get the "evilness" of arguments.callee. Many languages provide access to the function that created the current execution context, why is it evil in javascript? The only issues I've seen noted is that it prevents certain optimisations, so while it might be detrimental to performance, it's hardly evil

Comment: @RobG It causes a lot of problems with optimization, apparently, and in "strict" mode it's disallowed. In the future, the feature will be removed from the language. I'm not well-schooled on the theory but I've heard none other than Brendan Eich himself speak on the degree to which it was a mistake.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the answer to my question is "no." That said, this pattern comes closest to what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This really, really all depends.  If you're looking for private variables, then you can easily return a function from the function -- an inner-function will contain access to its parent's scope.

```
var outer_function = (function () {
    var private_var = "secret",
        public_var  = "public",

        inner_function = function () {
            return private_var;
        };

    inner_function.public_var = public_var;
    return inner_function;
}());
```

`outer_function` now equals `inner_function`, with the benefit of having access to the enclosed data.  Any properties attached to the inner (in the way you did) will now be accessible as public properties of `outer`.

To this end, you can return, say, a constructor for a class, with public-static properties, with the enclosed vars acting as private-static properties, shared between every instance of the "class" you build.

Comment: we think alike :-)  Your points are good, but exposing properties for configuration etc. on the function itself is sometimes useful. It's possible to do both of course.

Comment: @Pointy I did, actually `inner_function.public_var = public_var;`. When returned to the outer scope, you can now call `outer_function.public_var;` and it will be equal to the value of the enclosed `public_var`, if it is a scalar, or will be a "pointer reference" to the enclosed `public_var`, if it's an object/function/array...  ...at least until somebody modifies the value of the publicly-exposed members, of course.

Comment: Ah ok, yes I see that. I don't know how I managed to miss that!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but if you ever want to read up some different design patterns that can be used when defining a javascript function, this is one of the best articles I've ever read on the topic:

http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/

Comment: There is only one way to declare a function, which is by a [function declaration](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13). There are a couple of ways of initialising a function though using a function expression and assignment.

Comment: yea.. I worded that badly didn't I, I've updated to reflect your comment @RobG

Comment: @RobG -- I think your comment here is worth a separate answer. +1 anyway. Thanks!